# How do you get a specific value from a dictionary that corresponds to a specific key, and add that value to a variable?

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, key, tweets

I'm having trouble working with dictionaries in python. I have a dictionary that looks like this, where keyword = 'alone' and value = '1' (and likewise for the rest of the elements in the dictionary):

`{'alone': '1', 'amazed' : '10', 'amazing' : '10', 'bad': '2', 'best': '10', 'better' : '9', 'excellent' : '10', 'excited' : '10', 'excite' : '10', 'excites' : '10', 'exciting' : '10', 'glad' : '8', 'god' : '5', 'good' : '6', 'great' : '7', 'hate' : '1', 'hurt' : '1', 'positive' : '6', 'thanks' : '4', 'tired' : '3'}`

I have to go through a text file of tweets, see if any of the words in a given tweet match any of the words in the dictionary, and then add the corresponding integer value to a variable sum_value.

My code right now looks like this, but I don't know if I'm adding the right value to the variable sum_value.

```
        sum_value = 0
        if word in dictionary:
                value = dictionary[keyword]
                sum_value += dictionary[value]
        else:
                continue
```

Basically, if a tweet is "I feel alone", the program should sense that there is a keyword match and add the corresponding value for the keyword 'alone' to sum_value. I don't know how to do this... Could somebody help me out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the value from a dictionary key with `dictionary['key']`

```
mydict={'alone': '1', 'amazed' : '10',
        'amazing' : '10', 'bad': '2',
        'best': '10', 'better' : '9',
        'excellent' : '10', 'excited' : '10',
        'excite' : '10', 'excites' : '10',
        'exciting' : '10', 'glad' : '8',
        'god' : '5', 'good' : '6',
        'great' : '7', 'hate' : '1',
        'hurt' : '1', 'positive' : '6',
        'thanks' : '4', 'tired' : '3'}

sum_value = 0 
word ='alone'
if word in mydict:    
    value = mydict[word]
    sum_value+= int(value)
    print(sum_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need for-loops too. For example, your code could look like this:

```
tweet = input("Tweet: ")

sum_value = 0

words = tweet.split()
print(words)

dictionary_words=dictionary.keys()

for i in dictionary_words:
    print(i)

for word in words:
    for i in dictionary:
        if word == i:
            sum_value = sum_value + int(dictionary[i])
    else:
        continue
        
print(sum_value)
```